# Quicksort decision tree

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, decision-tree

I have just spent a couple of hours trying to represent the decision tree for the quicksort algorithm on a set of elements (and I also searched the web). I would like to know what each node actually represents. Is it the comparison between two sets (resulting from the call to **Partition**)? or just the comparison between two elements of the set?
I hope that my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to call a decision.  Since the only thing that can have different outcome is the choice of pivot element, I think that each edge in your tree is such a choice.  A node is thus a partially partitioned array, with marks for the intervals yet to be sorted.  In other words, you need a list of pivot indices in addition to the array in each node.